# Symfony 3: Curl GET timeout when used from a controller but work from command side

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I try to find a solution to this problem for the past few days but i dont find what is the issue here.

So the problem is simple but realy weird. I cant use curl (GET) from a controller in symfony.

I try to implement a simple form, You enter your mail in a form, send it, then it called the API from haveibeenpwned.com (great site, you should check ! ). The answer is basicly telling you if your mail has been "hacked", by sending you a json format string.

So i try my code in a simple php script. -> OK

Try my code in a command, and use the command on the server. -> OK

I call the command in my controller. -> FAIL
I test my curl script in the controller. -> FAIL

All time the code fail it's always "error : Failed connect to haveibeenpwned.com:443; Operation now in progress"

But since the code actualy work in a simple PHP script, and when i used the command I create on server side, i dont understant why the controller fail.

Here are the command

```
class checkMailCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('curl:checkMail')
        ->setDescription('Check Mail')
        ->addArgument('emailCheck', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'What\'s the email address we check?');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $account = $input->getArgument('emailCheck');

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/".$account,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "User-Agent: Pwnage-Checker-For-Safe-Portal",
            "api-version: 2"
        ),
    ));
    $output->writeln($curl);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err){
        $output->writeln("error : ".$err);
    }
    else{
        $output->writeln($response);
    }
}
```

}

and the controller function:

```
    public function checkMailAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(checkMailType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $message = null;
    $response = null;
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'curl:checkMail',
            'emailCheck' => $form["checkMail"]->getdata()
        ));

        $output = new BufferedOutput();

        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output
        $response = $output->fetch();

        //$response = json_decode($response, true);
    }

    return $this->render('EXTgetcurlBundle:hibp:check.html.twig', array(
        "message"               => $message,
        "response"               => $response,
        "form"                  => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

To be very clear, this code is working like a charm when i use it on my server, with the command

```
php bin/console curl:checkMail [mail]
```

and when i use it inside a simple test.php" and print_r the result.

If someone have any idea, it would be very appreciate.

Comment: If it works locally, then it must be in the server settings that manage access? Have you allowed external access to the port it listens to for mail? I am guessing, but I think your message never arrives so there is never a response, despite finding and connecting to the server.

Comment: The test are all executed on the server, so the command and the script can contact the external API, which is contact throught the 443 port.

This is why it's so strange :/

Comment: Ok, so the message is valid is the same and valid? And you can actually reach the server in different ways? It just fails during testing with curl? Aren't you then missing something in your curl call? The error message does not say whether you are using http or https, are you prefixing or have you tried prefixing http:// or http:// to your call address? I mean, I see it in the code, but does it actually get sent?

Comment: More context :

The test are all realise on a devellopment server.

Test 1 is : Taking the code, replace the $form by a valid email, and copy it into a test.php. This is working. So i can assume my curl code is working.

Test 2 : runing the command on the server again with php bin/console curl:checkMail test@exemple.com, this is working, so i can assume that my code is ok too inside the symfony command.

Test 3 : calling the command from my controller. This fail with a timout.

Test 4 : copy paste the code from test 1 inside the controller and dump the result. This fail too.

Comment: Double post sorry message too long. To answer your question, the error told me that he used the port 443, so i can assume that he used https like i write it. The big question is : did this even go out or not ? Or is the answer i dont catch ? And why is this working when i use exactly the same code by calling the same command on the command line, and not inside the controller ?

Comment: can you use some program to check outgoing traffic from your program?

Comment: Did you have any advice regarding this ? I use a Red Hat 8/apache/php7 for this project.

Comment: Not one specifically for this purpose, but I think you'd want to look at port monitoring software and you can probably write your  outgoing messages to a logfile straight from PHP itself. That way you have both ends covered. You could also check out this [list of monitoring tools](https://blog.serverdensity.com/80-linux-monitoring-tools-know/) and maybe [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/604998/monitor-tcp-traffic-on-specific-port). I hope you will find something useful in there, don't forget to answer your own question when you do solve this issue.

Comment: Additionally, you can try calling different webservices with simpler messages to see if the problem isn't your curl install itself that's unable to call ANY webservices.

Comment: Thank for the tips, i find out that i was behind a proxy on this server. The proxy allow to open the connection to internet, and it's work apparently since my command is working. It's mean that the controller is not using it, or dont do the request properly. Maybe i dont configure something somewhere to use this proxy when i try to curl ?

Comment: Then you should have a call to this proxy somewhere, either as its name or directly the ip. Ctrl + shift + f for both? Symfony if I recall correctly has 2 configurations, one for production and one for development & testing

Comment: Yes there the 2 configuration app.php and app_dev.php
But why should i need to configure something when a simple call of my command if working ? This is not working only when i use the controller, so real question is, what the controller do, that's the command or service not (service is working too when i call it from a command). Did he not used the proxy, wich is configure at server level and not at php or apache level ?

Comment: If your code works locally, but not on your server, but the configs are functionally the same on both, then wouldn't the problem likely be in your cache or some other stored piece of information somewhere that should be reloaded?

Comment: Ok so i find the answer to this problem, and i'm a retard ...

So apparently the proxy is set on the envirnment of my user, but not apache. So of course, this work when i call a command since i used my ssh user, the controller is call by apache, which dont have a user envirnoment with the proxy, and apache has not the proxy set.  

To avoid issue i set the proxy on CURL with this new lines :  
`curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);  
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);  
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy.localnet.com');  `
And this work !

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me @G_V at the end it was a bad understanding of the server configuration.